# Woocommerce Shop Page Product Margin

Tags: css, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, margin, woocommerce-theming

I'm having the hardest time getting rid of this product right-margin on my custom WooCommerce theme, located on the Shop page. Everything I've tried doesn't seem to work. Here's the HTML output:

```
<div class="products">
 <div class="col-md-4 post-17 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first instock featured shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="margin-right:0 !important;">
 <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/product-1/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"><img width="300" height="252" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/LCL_WEB-_31-300x252.png" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="LCL_WEB-_31" title="LCL_WEB-_31"><h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Product #1</h2>
<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>25.00</span></span>
```

```
            <div class="col-md-4 post-23 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail  instock featured shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="margin-right:0 !important;">
<a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/product-2/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"><img width="300" height="255" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/LCL_WEB-_29-2-300x255.png" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="LCL_WEB-_29" title="LCL_WEB-_29"><h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Product #2</h2>
<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>250.00</span></span>
```

```
            <div class="col-md-4 post-29 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail  instock featured shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="margin-right:0 !important;">
<a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/product-3/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"><img width="300" height="255" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/LCL_WEB-_33-300x255.png" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="LCL_WEB-_33" title="LCL_WEB-_33"><h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Product #3</h2>
<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>450.00</span></span>
```

Here's
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX4CL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the different products next to each other use inline-block:

```
.product {
    display: inline-block
}
```

The display property `block` always fills up the full width of its parent.